# iOS App Store Company Name Above App Name

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to change the seller name that shows up in the app store (name that shows up above app name)? Currently it says my name, but I want it to show my business name.  Does apple allow this change?  If so, how?

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but somewhat off topic for SO in that it isn't about programming. The best way to get a definitive answer *and* begin whatever process might be necessary is to call Apple's developer support number. Good luck.

Comment: Not a programming question. Doesn't belong to SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not about programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change your developer program membership from a personal to corporate membership, contact Apple.  Many developers who started out as individuals have since changed to a corporate membership.

Comment: Hmm, I only have a DBA name for my Sole Proprietorship, will they still allow this?

Comment: No. They stopped accepting DBAs a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Apple may allow changing your developer enrollment if you incorporate your business under your desired company name and have legal incorporation papers ready to show Apple.

Answer (score 0):

When you signed up, you had an option to select a business or a name and it said you couldn't change this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow Apple's faq on iTunes connect:

> Frequently Asked Questions:
>   It appears that my Team Information Update has been processed. When will my Company and Seller names as displayed on the App Store be updated? 
>   Your Company and Seller names should generally be updated on the App Store as soon as the contract(s) initiated through your Team Information Update have completed processing. Due to certain specific system processing issues, this may take a few hours, so please check the App Store to see if the information has been updated following your Team Information Update completing processing. Your Team Information Update completing processing is indicated by your updated contracts (as indicated in the Team Information Update email sent to your Team Agent) moving into the Contracts In Effect section of the Contracts, Tax and Banking module of iTunes Connect.
>
> If your information has not been updated on the App Store more than 48 hours after your Team Information Update completing processing, click here to contact us.